# Sum all selected rows in jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a amount column and have used this https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html to calculate the total for on page and off page into the footer.

There is also this example which alerts the total amount on page and off page.
https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/api.html

What i am trying to achieve is how to sum the values of selected rows of the salary columns

Here is one I built on jsfiddle with the rows selection done and a footer total done.

But I can't figure out how I can add a sum value of the total of selected rows in the bottom left hand corner cell

http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/190/

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column( 4 )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            } );

        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
            '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
        );
    }
} );

$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
} );
```

Comment: you want select value count?

Comment: yes so when you click a row, the salary gets summed in the bottom left footer

Comment: basically to sum all rows that have active class against it from row selection

Comment: How do you mean 'active class against it from row selection'? Right now, your table rows have either `.odd` or `.even` as classes. Which one is considered active and which isn't?

Comment: apologies, the active class name is "selected" not "active". So when you click a row, the tr class gets a "selected" class added to highlight the row wich has been selected. I want to be able to click multiple rows and the sum will show in the bottom left footer

Comment: check the answer may be u need this @adamgouldie

Answer (score 2):

Add a class of `.sum` in the `th` element that shows the total sum. Also, create a `sum` variable and initialize it at the top of your javascript code.
Then, change your code that toggles the `selected` class to this:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        var price = parseInt(($(this).find('td').last().html()).replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
           sum -= price;
        } else {
           sum += price;
        }
        $('.sum').html(sum);
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
} );
```

And here is a working [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/204/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/209/)

```
 $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('#button').trigger('click');
        console.log($('tfoot tr > th').eq(1).html( '$'+ $('#selectedtotal').html()));        

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalSUM = 0;
$("tbody tr.selected").each(function () {
    var getValue = $(this).find("td:eq(4)").html().replace("$", "");
    var filteresValue = getValue.replace(/\,/g, '');
    totalSUM += Number(filteresValue)
    console.log(filteresValue);
});
alert(totalSUM);
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/197/)**

Comment: Thanks but this example doesn't automatically sum all the values into the footer box. You have to click a button to do the calculation

Answer (score 0):

You could check if a row has been selected or not by **`$(this)[0].classList.contains("selected")`**. Then add the amount of the 5th column of the row **`$(this).find(':nth-child(5)')`** to the amount of the **`$('sum')`**:

```
if($(this)[0].classList.contains("selected"))
{
        $('#sum').html(
            parseFloat($('#sum').html()) + 
            parseFloat($(this).find(':nth-child(5)').html().replace(/[$,]/g, "")));
}

else
{
        $('#sum').html(
        parseFloat($('#sum').html()) -
        parseFloat($(this).find(':nth-child(5)').html().replace(/[$,]/g, "")));
}
```

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/205/)